# Microsoft Visual Studio Can't find File when using Step In Command

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, fortran, step-into

I am currently working on a Fortran code on Microsoft Visual studios 2022. Until recently, I was able to step into different subroutines and suddenly I'm getting an error

"___________ not found"

"You need to find _______ to view the source for the current call stack frame"

"Try one of the following options:

-Browse and find _______..."

You can view disassembly in the Disassembly window. To always view disassembly for missing source files, change the setting in the Options Dialog."

When I browse for the file, it finds it just fie. When I try to step over the subroutine, it works fine. I only get this error when I try to step into the subroutine file.

So far I have tried the following:

Tools>Import and Export Settings Wizard > Reset all settings

and

Tools > Options > Debugging > General > Check enable just my code and enable "Warn if no user code on launch"

So far nothing has worked

Comment: Welcome, please [tour] and [ask]. Which compiler are you using. What kind of settings in Visual Studio?

Comment: You've probably stepped into a language support routine, not your routine.

Comment: Please show the details of what exactly you are doing. Which subroutine you cannot step into? Show specific examples, otherwise the question cannot be answered.

Comment: It isn't necessarily what's tripping you, but if you updated Visual Studio recently, there has been an issue where it's necessary to go to Tools / Options, then select Debugging / General and disable the option "Load debug symbols in external process (Native only)".  I know this caused major issues with Fortran debugging, but I don't remember if it interfered with the step-into functionality or if it only caused problems with watches and variable inspection.